# Can't login to WSL Xrdp using Xorg

Tags: xorg, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xrdp

I've been using it everyday for months but today for some reason i couldn't log in.
The password still worked in the CMD but didn't work on the Xorg login screen.
I'm pretty noob  at this so i need some help. What can i do?
I already tried changing the password with the passwd command but it still doesn't work, change it a couple times. Is the password in the wsl cmd the same for Xorg?

Comment: What is the error message you are receiving?